# add-migration not adding model to migration file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have created a model called "SupportTicket" and tried to create a migration to scaffold the database however, the migration file came back as blank. I have migrations enabled.

The SupportTicket model

```
public class SupportTicket
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The DAO file:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {
            public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
            {
                // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
                var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                // Add custom user claims here

                userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", FirstName.ToString()));
                userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("LastName", LastName.ToString()));


                return userIdentity;
            }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }

        public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {

            public DbSet<SupportTicket> SupportTickets { get; set; }
            public ApplicationDbContext()
                : base("DefaultConnection")
            {
            }

            public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
            {
                return new ApplicationDbContext();
            }
        }
```

The output migration file:

```
public partial class added_support_ticket : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

What am I doing wong? This is my first time using Migrations and I have very little clue what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Try to build the solution and delete the old migrations and run the migration again.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the migration file and re-created it and the migration worked.